# MySQL overlapping dates, none conflicting

Tags: php, mysql, date, range, overlapping

I've seen lots of threads about date ranges in MySQL but I still don't seem to be able to find an answer for what I'm looking for so any help will be greatly received.

I have a MySQL table with 3 columns, date - startTime - finishTime.  The date is a MySQL 'date' type field and the start and finish times are both 'time' type fields.

Say for example I have an entry in the database as follows, lets call this session 1;

```
date = 2011-06-30, startTime = 09:00:00, finishTime = 11:00:00
```

If I come to add another session I need to make sure that it doesn't conflict with an existing session.  So the following would fail because it falls in between session 1 start and finish times.

```
date = 2011-06-30, startTime = 10:00:00, finishTime = 12:00:00
```

So the record can only be inserted 'AFTER' or 'BEFORE' an existing session.

I'm using PHP/MySQL and am going on the basis that a query can be run and if there 'are' matching results then, fail, if there 'arent' matching results then insert.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what happens when there is a session with `09:00 - 11:00` and the new one is `11:00 - 13:00`. Collision or not?

Comment: @Rob: Then, the `BETWEEN` solutions will not work as they will give collision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'm using PHP/MySQL and am going on the basis that a query can be run and if there 'are' matching results then, fail, if there 'arent' matching results then insert.*

Well, try this. Here `:date:` is the date of the entry you are going to add, and `:start-time:` and `:finish-time:` are its start and finish times respectively.

```
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        TableName
    WHERE
        `date` = :date: AND
        ( :start-time: BETWEEN startTime AND finishTime OR
          :finish-time: BETWEEN startTime AND finishTime OR
          startTime BETWEEN :start-time: AND :finish-time:
          )
) AS `Clash`
```

Comment: I have just realised that this reports a collision if the two sessions clash only at their endpoints (i.e. the endpoint of one is the start of another). This may not be what you intend. This happens because `BETWEEN` is inclusive. The query may be rewritten to eliminate use of `BETWEEN` in favour of the strict comparison operators `<` and `>`.

Comment: @Hammerite: Exactly. `x BETWEEN a AND b`, it should be replaced by `a <= x AND x < b`

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem of date overlapping detection, my first idea was to do something like Hammerite's solution but i found this solution incomplete mainly because there are too many possible scenarios where two date ranges can be in conflict:

The query I ended up using to solve this was something like:

```
/* overlapping dates */
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
WHERE `date` = $date AND
  NOT (
    `start_time` < $start_time and `finish_time` < $start_time
    OR
    `start_time` > $end_time and `finish_time` > $end_time
  )
```

For more details you can [check my blog here](http://emont01.blogspot.com/2013/02/howto-detect-date-collisions-or.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would structure the table in a different way. I'd have two columns, both `datetime` type, named `session_start` and `session_end`.

Logic is: you cannot insert new session if it's `session_start` time isn't `>` or `<` than old session `session_end`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $date, $startTime and $finishTime are your PHP variables that store the date, start time and finish time respectively to be inserted.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `session`
SELECT \'' . $date . '\', \'' . $startTime . '\', \'' . $finishTime . '\'
FROM `session`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM `session`
    WHERE `date` = \'' . $date . '\'
    AND \'' . $startTime . '\' BETWEEN `startTime` and `finishTime`
)';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if the new session's start time is not in between the existing session's start and finish times, but its finish time is?

Comment: Yeah, my bad I missed to add those conditions. Thanks for pointing them out

Answer (score 0):

I would use the simple:

```
INSERT INTO session
  ( `date`, startTime, finishTime )
  SELECT
  ( $date, $startTime, $finishTime )
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT
          *
      FROM
          session
      WHERE
            `date` = $date 
        AND $startTime <  finishTime 
        AND  startTime < $finishTime 

    )
```

The `<` should be changed to `<=` if you want the two periods `09:00 - 11:00` and `11:00 - 13:00` to collide.