# Overlap of time slot

Tags: php, mysql

i have made a booking system where user can select time slot enter start & end time & save those values into MySql. Now i have found an issue where User A has booked time slot from 3-4. Now User B wants to book time slot 2.30-4.30. At present it is allowing User B to select the time slot which i don't want.Tried to code for it but not getting the desired result. 
Please Help!

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="testmra"; // Database name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect");

mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
$sname=$_SESSION['usr_name'];


$room = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtrname']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtname']);
$purpose = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtpurpose']);
$attendee = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['attendee']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtdate']);
$btime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['btime']);
$etime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['etime']);

$query="SELECT starttime,endtime FROM bookingdetails WHERE date = '$date' AND room='$room' ";
$result=mysqli_query($query);
$num=mysqli_num_rows($result);

$i=0;
  while ($i <= $num)
  {
    $MinValue=mysqli_result($result,$i,"starttime");
    $MaxValue=mysqli_result($result,$i,"endtime");
   if (($btime < $MaxValue) && ($MinValue < $etime)) {
        $overflowed=true;
    }
    $i++;
   }

   if ($overflowed)
   {
       //Error message
      header("location:karma.php");
       echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert(" Time Slot is overlapping.Change the time slot")';
    echo '</script>';
    }
   else
   {
      //Save to database
             $sql="INSERT INTO bookingdetails  (room,name,purpose,attendee,date,starttime,endtime,status_id)VALUES('$room','$name','$purpose','$attendee','$date','$btime','$etime','2')";
     }


    if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
      {
        echo "Record added";

        }
    else
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: You can do a single sql request to check if your time slot overlaps others: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545947/mysql-range-date-overlap-check

Comment: @MrShibby. Thanks for the link but the logic i tried is correct ?

Comment: Well instead of doing your request and then loop through the results, you can do the single request which count the overlapping bookings. If you find more than 0 then the user need to change his time slot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql - INSERT date range into date columns IF dates don't overlap with existing ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434839/mysql-insert-date-range-into-date-columns-if-dates-dont-overlap-with-existing)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a sql request that count existing overlappings:

```
SELECT count(*) WHERE $requested_start < endtime
AND $requested_end > starttime
AND date = $date
AND status_id = 2;
```

You can now use this result to check if the time slot is available or not:

```
$overlappings = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

// If there is no overlapping
if($overlappings[0] <= 0){
  // time slot is available
}
```

Comment: There's no need to check first, but if you are going to check first, then you need to do it as part of a transaction.

Comment: My mistake, using num_rows with the result of a count() will return 1. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Sir just wanted to ask if i have written the code properly ? Because i used the above code it didn't inserted the value into db also.

Comment: With your current code $overlappings is always equals to 1 so your insert query will never be executed.

Comment: So what changes i need to do ?

Comment: Check my edit, try mysqli_fetch_row to fetch the result of the count query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
 $sql = "select room_no FROM roominfo WHERE room_no NOT IN (SELECT roomno FROM guestrocordtransac WHERE '".$format_checkin."' between checkin AND checkout and roomtype='".$roomtype."' UNION SELECT roomno FROM guestrocordtransac WHERE '".$format_checkout."' BETWEEN checkin AND checkout and roomtype='".$roomtype."') and roomtype='".$roomtype."' ";
 $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
 if(mysql_num_rows($retval)== 0 ||mysql_num_rows($retval)== null )
{
  ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
alert("Please select another date/Type")</script>
 <?php
 }
 else{   ///inserrt code///}
```

This is a sample code ...Replace the format checkin with your time ...I think this might help you..

Comment: Will Try this but confused. 1. Why have you used room_no & what does guestrocordtransac means

Comment: apart from start and end time in booking details what are the other fields do you have...do you have unique id there

Comment: Sir u misunderstood it. This page is to check for overlap of time slot for a particular room only

Comment: SELECT starttime,endtime FROM bookingdetails WHERE room NOT IN (SELECT room FROM bookingdetails WHERE '".$btime."' between starttime AND endtime  UNION SELECT room FROM bookingdetails WHERE '".$etime."' between starttime AND endtime ) AND room='$room' and date = '$date'";

you have to change ur code like this

Comment: Ok Will try it .Thanks for the help. But do you think this will work out ?

Comment: just copy the code and try it in wampserver provide with dummy date and time...For me its not the time its about date...Thats the only reason i'm not sure of...other than that it works fine