# MySQL date range check before inserting into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date-range

This is not a duplicate question my query i have in my fiddle demo handles overlapping date from my database. What i am after is a way to run the query on the date range $startdate and $enddate before inserting the dates into MySQL. Basically i want to check if each employee as enough days holiday left in that years holiday entitlement.

I am try to check which year each date in a date range is in before insert into MYSQL. Each year for each employee start on a different day

```
Eg. jon started on 2013-10-10 so his year is  
2013-10-10 to 2014-10-10 
2014-10-10 to 2015-10-10
```

At the moment my query checks the date when they have already been inserted into MYSQL (h.date) the e.startdate works out each year from when they started. Who do I check each date between $startdate, $enddate before inserting the dates.

I have setup a Fiddle demo which works when dates are already in the datebase

```
$startdate ='2015-10-05';
$enddate ='2015-10-20';

    SELECT 
            e.name AS Employee,
            CONCAT(
                CEIL(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.startdate)/365), 
                ' (',
                DATE_ADD(e.startdate, INTERVAL FLOOR(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.startdate)/365) YEAR), ' to ',        
                DATE_ADD(e.startdate, INTERVAL CEIL(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.startdate)/365) YEAR),
                ')'
                ) as Year,
            COUNT(h.date) AS Holidays_Taken,
            SUM(h.hours) AS Hours
        FROM employees AS e
        LEFT JOIN holidays_taken AS h ON e.id = h.empid
        WHERE e.id = 1
        GROUP BY Year
```

[[Fiddle Demo]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/371a7/15)

I hope someone can help Thanks

Thanks I forgot to mention at the hours for each day the employee works is different so I us this query to insert the hours for each day on holiday eg. jon (empId 1) works 10 hours on monday, 6 on Tuesday etc.

```
    $sql= "select  empId,
'".$holidayStart."' as date,
case dayname('".$holidayStart."')
    when 'Sunday' then Sun
    when 'Monday' then Mon
    when 'Tuesday' then Tue
    when 'Wednesday' then Wed
    when 'Thursday' then Thu
    when 'Friday' then Fri
    when 'Saturday' then Sat
else 0 end as hours
from employees where empId = '".$employee."'"  ;
 $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

then the database

```
id   empid   Mon  Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
102    1      10   6   4   10  10  0   0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql - INSERT date range into date columns IF dates don't overlap with existing ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434839/mysql-insert-date-range-into-date-columns-if-dates-dont-overlap-with-existing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i got the problem correctly (i couldn't find the question mark :-) ). Hope the following query helps you anyway:

```sql
SET @hoursPerDay := 8;
SET @startdate := DATE('2015-10-05');
SET @enddate   := DATE('2015-10-20');
SET @empid := 1;

SELECT years.*, holidays.*,
    GREATEST(holidays.startdate, years.yearStartDay) AS holidaysStartDay,
    LEAST(holidays.enddate, years.yearEndDay) AS holidaysEndDay
FROM (
    SELECT e.name,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, e.startdate, h.date) AS yearNr,
        DATE_ADD(
            e.startdate, INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, e.startdate, h.date) YEAR
        ) AS yearStartDay,
        DATE_ADD(
            DATE_ADD(e.startdate, 
                INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, e.startdate, h.date) +1 YEAR
            ), INTERVAL -1 DAY
        ) AS yearEndDay,
        e.holidays,
        SUM(h.hours) AS hoursTaken,
        e.holidays * @hoursPerDay - SUM(h.hours) AS hoursLeft
    FROM (
        SELECT empid, DATE, hours
        FROM holidays_taken h 
        -- need union all if didnt have holidays in that year yet
        UNION ALL SELECT @empid AS empid, @startdate AS DATE, 0 AS hours
        UNION ALL SELECT @empid AS empid, @enddate   AS DATE, 0 AS hours
    ) h
    JOIN employees e ON e.id = h.empid
    WHERE h.empid = @empid /* @todo replace with correct employeeID */
    GROUP BY e.id, e.name, e.holidays, yearStartDay, yearEndDay
) years
JOIN (SELECT @startdate AS startdate, @enddate AS enddate) holidays /* @todo replace with $startdate and $enddate */
WHERE holidays.startdate BETWEEN years.yearStartDay AND years.yearEndDay
   OR holidays.enddate   BETWEEN years.yearStartDay AND years.yearEndDay
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10a1d/15

You don't need to use session variables. Just replace them with values in PHP. 
Delete everything in the outer select that you don't need.

So what does that query do: 
The inner select does almost the same as your query but

- It can handle the case, that an employees year starts on Feb. 29
- The `UNION ALL` part creates a new year if the employee dind't have holidays in that year yet.
- The last day of a year doesn't overlap with the first day of the next year.

Then it looks for intersections between the new defined holidays and all employee years. Calculates then the date range of the new holidays for each employee year.

To test more cases, replase the session variable defintitions with:

```sql
-- sample 2: first time taking holidays in a year
SET @startdate := DATE('2017-10-05');
SET @enddate   := DATE('2017-10-20');
SET @empid := 1;


-- sample 3: first year of employee who starts on Feb. 29th
SET @startdate := DATE('2016-10-05');
SET @enddate   := DATE('2016-10-20');
SET @empid := 2;


-- sample 4: second year of employee who starts on Feb. 29th
SET @startdate := DATE('2017-10-05');
SET @enddate   := DATE('2017-10-20');
SET @empid := 2;
```

Comment: Great answer but I only want to query the date for employees start date the query $satrtdate and $enddate (date range) [http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2a0d]   I do not need to check the holiday datebase so the result  read jon  {yearNr 0 yearStartDay October, 10 2014 00:00:00 yearEndDay October, 09 2015 00:00:00 days  = 5 , yearNr 1 yearStartDay October, 10 2015 00:00:00 yearEndDay October, 09 2016 00:00:00 days  = 10 }  thanks can you help

Comment: Your query  works great for me but forgot to mention hours worked  for each day is different  I have edit the original question How do I incorporate this into your query please Thanks

Comment: I completly missed the weekend problem. So i changed the query and added the ranges of taking holidays for each year. You can loop every day within that ranges in PHP and calculate how many hours the amployee would work in that ranges. While that is stil possible to do in SQL, it would be difficult to maintain. And you should consider, that there are not only weekends but holidays like christmas too. So you will need a holiday calendar to solve that issue.