# MYSQL Constraint on new rows based existing min and max values in rows

Tags: mysql, constraints

This is my table:

```
 CREATE TABLE price_group(
  price_group_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  price_group_number INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  price_group_minimum_surplus_percent INT NOT NULL,
  price_group_maximum_surplus_percent INT NOT NULL
  );
```

How do i set a constraint so new rows can't be added if the value range between minimum and maximum overlaps existing ranges?

Comment: You can construct the query accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, so how would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434839/mysql-insert-date-range-into-date-columns-if-dates-dont-overlap-with-existing/30437434#30437434

Comment: Ill check it out, thank you.