# how to avoid this overlapping row in my phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some field in allocate classroom table like course_id, room_id, day_id, time_from, time_to.

Now i want to avoid overlapping on every course which try to allocate second time in this time..

suppose there have one row

```
cse101, 101 room, Saturday, 14:00, 16:00.
```

next time when i try to allocate new course in exact room exact day, between 15:00-18:00 i will get a message in this time you cannot allocate a new course.. cause there has already cse101 allocated you can add your course after 16:00.

i want to do it with php...

how can i do it ?

Comment: Right before inserting the new entry, try to select any existing entries in the same time window for that room. If that returns any rows at all, don't insert the new entry.

Comment: but in this process 14:00 16:00 will work but 15:00-18:00 how will work.. that i asked between that time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434839/mysql-insert-date-range-into-date-columns-if-dates-dont-overlap-with-existing/30437434#30437434

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic for an overlap is as follows:

```
select a.*
from allocates a
where a.day_id = $day_id and
      a.room_id = $room_id and 
      a.time_from < $time_to and
      a.time_to > $time_from;
```

Two time periods overlaps when one begins before the second ends and the first ends after the first begins.

Note:  I used variables in the above example, but you should code it with proper parameters.