# Mysqli unique range of 2 columns

Tags: mysql

For the last couple of day I have been searching how to make the range of 2 columns in mysqli unique. For example column1 has value 2 and column2 has value 6. If the user tries to input in any of the columns 3,4,5 as a different row it must return an error. I could do that in php checking all the row but it will slow down the perfomance when too many records.

For my scenarion I have a From data(stored in unix timestamp) and Till data(again stored in unix timestamp).

Take for example

`1497913200(20/06/2017)` and `1498518000(27/06/2017)`

Anything between these 2 dates must be invalid,

eg `22/06/2017-29/06/2017` or `18/06/2017-26/06/2017`

while `28/06/2017 - 03/07/2017` or `12/06/2017-19/06/2017` are valid.

I think you get the point but I can elaborate if needed.

I obviously know how to make unique multiple column but not the range of these columns. That's the part i am struggling with.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I do not even have the table yet, because I want to get the logic behind this done first. As I do not want to go down the wrong road. Table or not the only "real" or sample data I have is the one provided above.

Comment: OK, well you could do worse than start here (even if I say so myself ;-) )... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434839/mysql-insert-date-range-into-date-columns-if-dates-dont-overlap-with-existing/30437434#30437434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to write a `TRIGGER` to perform this check, e.g.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER date_check_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON `table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @EXISTING_RECORD_COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE NEW.date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
    IF (@EXISTING_RECORD_COUNT > 0) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' set message_text='Invalid date, a range already exists';
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: does that prevent user input on insertion? or afterwards?

Comment: Yes, that does. It will show an error message and won't allow the users to insert the records.

Comment: Ok I get what you are trying to do although it needs adjustment to my scenario so I will not mark as an accepted answer just yet

Comment: Marking the answer is trivial, what I am trying to say is, you can't have unique constraint to perform the type of scanning we want to do. And hence, it's better to write a trigger.

Comment: so in other words you are saying its either a trigger or a higher level approach which means I should do this in php and be done with it

Comment: You need to do it in database. It will work similar to how `CONSTRAINT` works, your `INSERT` will fail and you will get error message. So yes, either trigger or in application (I'd prefer trigger).

Comment: That covers and wraps things up then. Thank you very much for all of your contribution. I have accepted and upvoted your answer. It does not directly answer it but it is the closest I can get it so I am happy with it.